# How to immediately force view to draw itself after closing Alert View by the user?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

the situation is like this:

if i don't have internet connection, i show UIAlertView to the user.
when the user press "try again", i call "do something".

the problem is the UIAlertView still show for seconds.after the user click "try again"

i tried like:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

but,it not works, cause even in the documents,if said the refresh will be
only when code control will return to the system, and that is not the case here.

thanking in advance.

```
///////////////////////////////////
if(somecondition)
{

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"NO INTERNET CONNECTION"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Try Again", nil];

        [alert show];
        [alert release];

                 return;
 }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons

    [self DoSomthing];                 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do some lengthy process in the callback from the alert, it will not hide until that callback returns.

So in other words, your doSomething method should not directly try to reconnect to the internet, but just have it spawn off the asynchronous call for doing this.

EDIT:
You may delay/detach execution of doSomething with this line of code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: so if i put the "dosomthing" after the "[alert release]".
then, how i can force the view to force refresh ?

meaning:

[alert show];
[alert release];
///////
//here force the view to refresh itself
///////

//after view refresh call dosomthing
[self doSomthing]

Comment: You should not need to force refresh since control will be returned to the system much sooner if you detach the lengthy process. Just calling doSomething later in the same method doesn't detatch it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to detect when the alert is dismissed, I added a line of code to hide it and spawn a new URLrequest, if that's what you need.

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
alert.hidden=YES;
[webnews loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:home]];
}
```

The request uses my UIWebView 'webnews' and the NSURL 'home', you will have to adapt these of course.